# Cannot enable my own SSL certificate on heroku

Tags: node.js, heroku, express, https

I host my website at heroku using my own domain name using node.js & express 4.x.
I have purchased SSL certificate and I want to add it to my website.

I use the following code to enable HTTPS support:

```
var fs = require('fs');
var http = require('http');
var https = require('https');
var privateKey  = fs.readFileSync('sec/private_server.key', 'utf8');
var certificate = fs.readFileSync('sec/server.crt', 'utf8');

var credentials = { key: privateKey, cert: certificate };


// launch http server
var httpServer = http.createServer(app).listen( process.env.PORT, process.env.IP || "0.0.0.0", function() {
    console.log('Listening on port %d', process.env.PORT);
});


// launch https server
var httpsServer = https.createServer(credentials, app).listen( 8443, process.env.IP || "0.0.0.0", function() {
    console.log('Listening HTTPS on port 8433' );
});
```

Launching the server and visiting it by https link shows that I this website still uses heroku certificate.

What do I do wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the Heroku SSL endpoint add-on.

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/ssl-endpoint

Comment: So without paying 20$ per month I cannot use my own certificates? Is there any explanation from heroku on why do they force me to pay them for stuff that I already own?

Comment: @Quest you can certainly use your certificate however you'd like without paying Heroku anything extra. The **only** limitation is that you won't be able to use it on sites hosted by Heroku without paying them for that additional service. If you don't think that feature is worth $20/mo then I'm sure you can live without SSL on your custom domain or find a competitor that offers that service for free.

Comment: @idbehold, yeah, found one already, digitalocean, 4 times cheaper.

Comment: Some options are to route the site though Cloudflare or Amazon Cloudfront, both offer SSL endpoints and the bonus of caching.

Comment: When you add the SSL:Endpoint Heroku creates an Amazon ELB which your certificate is attached too. That ELB is flexible in that it grows depending on your sites traffic demands. If you're hosting a low traffic site then this cost is sometimes a lot to swallow but for high traffic sites it's pretty small.